# Странное поведение Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#

Решил пощупать приложение с окнами, и тут возникла проблема.
Есть код:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 {
    int value = rnd.Next(1, 6);
    switch (value)
    {
      case 1:
         label3.Text = "";
         break;
      case 2:
         label3.Text = "";
         break;
      case 3:
         label3.Text = "";
         break;
      case 4:
         label3.Text = "";
         break;
      case 5:
         label3.Text = "";
         break;

    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    label4.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
  }
```

Однако `Thread.Sleep(2000);` не работает. Когда я запускаю программу, она как будто игнорирует слип, и в label.4 сразу выводится 8.
Почему так и как выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: В каком методе запускаете этот код? По идее, Sleep должен отработать в UI-потоке. Т.е. ваше окно зависнет на 16 секунд и выведет 8 в `label4`.

Comment: @Vlad А можно ли это обойти, что бы рандомилось и отображалось каждые 2 секунды?

Comment: @Regent Действия разные, я просто выпилил текст который должен отображаться. А на счет case 6 ступил. valie - очепятка.

Comment: @SKProCH а изменение текста `label3` вообще имеет отношение к вопросу? Или вопрос только про `label4`? Если не имеет, то этот `switch` имеет смысл убрать из кода в вопросе.

Comment: @Regent  *label4* это отображение того, сколько раз уже выполнился *for*.

Comment: @SKProCH да, я вижу по коду. Мой вопрос в том, действительно ли в коде вопроса нужен `label3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ничего странного. Когда вы меняете текст надписи - ее регион в окне инвалидируется и в очередь сообщений посылается сообщение WM_PAINT. Но это сообщение может быть обработано только после того, как ваш цикл завершит работу.

Есть три способа исправить такую ситуацию. Первый - старый - вызов `Application.DoEvents()` внутри цикла, чтобы "разгрести" накопившиеся сообщения:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  label4.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Второй способ - объявить метод асинхронным (async) и использовать `await Task.Delay` для ожидания:

```
async void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    label4.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
  }
}
```

Не забудьте только установить обработчик события `Application.ThreadException` при использовании `async void`-метода.

Третий способ - можно вынести цикл в отдельный поток.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()`? Нуууууу. Окно ж зависнет на две секунды.